# Iterating through over a map of lists in terraform

Tags: foreach, terraform, flatten

I'm trying to attach list of policies to roles and I have defined my variable as follows:

```
variable "role_map_user_policies" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    role1 = ["policy_arn1", "policy_arn2"]
    role2 = ["policy_arn1", "policy_arn2", "policy_arn3"]
  }
```

my resource block as follows

```
locals {

  policy_attachments  = flatten([for roleName, policies in var.role_map_user_policies :
                                  [for policy_arn in  policies: {
                                      roleName       = roleName
                                      policy_arn = policy_arn
                                    }
                                  ]
  ])
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "customer_managed_policy_attachment" {
  
  for_each = {
        for entry in local.policy_attachments: "${entry.roleName}.${entry.policy_arn}" => entry

  }
  role = each.value.roleName
  policy_arn = each.value.policy_arn
```

Here it shows errors like "unresolved reference" over entry.roleName and entry.policy_arn each.value.roleName each.value.policy_arn

I'm not able to get it where it is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

expecting it should assign the role name and list of policies to the arugments

Comment: Why do you have `**` in your code? What does it mean?

Comment: Also what is the **full** error message?

Comment: ** got added for bold.. I have removed them now..  And error is already metnioned which is as below: "unresolved reference" over entry.roleName and entry.policy_arn each.value.roleName each.value.policy_arn